# Handling typeError through Ember.onerror

Tags: ember.js

I would like to be able to be able to handle javascript errors in my Ember application and display a generic modal defined in my application's templates. I'm able to process errors by defining a function for Ember.onerror, but haven't been able to find a way to trigger an event or action against my application for certain error types, for instance a TypeError.

Below is a sample of how I've approached defining `Ember.onerror`

```
App.report_errors = (error) ->
  console.log "error", error
  # Would like to be able to use something like the below line
  # to call an action on the application route
  @send "showError"

  # Log to api 

Em.onerror = App.report_errors
```

Here is a full example fiddle illustrating what I would like to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/mandrakus/c8E3x/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution (courtesy Alex Speller) adds an errorReporter object which is injected during initialization with the ability to access the router and therefore router actions.

```
App.initializer
  name: 'errorReporter'
  initialize: (container) ->
    container.injection 'reporter:error', 'router', 'router:main'
    container.injection 'route', 'errorReporter', 'reporter:error'

    reporter = container.lookup 'reporter:error'
    Em.onerror = (error) ->
      reporter.report error

App.ErrorReporter = Em.Object.extend
  report: (error) ->
      console.log "error", error
      #Would like to be able to use something like the below line
      #to call an action on the application route
      @router.send "showError" 

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  actions: 
    error: (error) -> @errorReporter.report error
    showError: ->
      console.log "displaying error"
      #the final application generate a modal or other notification
      alert "Generic Error Message"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
App.report_errors = function (error) {
    App.__container__.lookup("route:application").send("showError", error);
};
```

Two potential problems:

- Using global App object. Not a big deal, unless you're trying to host two ember apps side-by-side
- Using the hidden **container** property. This might change name/location in the future, but as I see it used all over the place, I doubt Ember team will remove it completely.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I actually had looked at this approach, but wanted to see if there was a more idiomatic way to solve it.